# Issue with iMessage on Mac

Tags: macos, iphone, catalina, sms

Lately my iMessage behave very funcky. I signed in and sign back out, I still didn't see messages from my iPhone. Even after wait a few days.

I decided to remove iMessage using App Cleaner.

Now when I lauch, I keep seeing

[image]

---

## I've also tried

to search for “imessage” in App Store, but I see nothing.

---

**Is there a way to quickly fix this?**

I just need my iMessage on my Mac to work again.

Comment: iMessage is a part of OS X/macOS so you can try a reinstall of OS X/macOS from OS X/macOS Recovery. See the link for instructions: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904.

Answer (score 1):

iMessage isn’t a “separate” or 3rd party application; [it’s built into macOS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202549).

You will have to reinstall macOS on top of your existing macOS installation to fix it as that will replace anything that you’ve removed.

Start from recovery by booting your Mac with the <kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> key combo held.  That will boot you into a recovery version of macOS.  Select only to “Reinstall macOS” on the existing disk that there.  Don’t wipe it, partition the disk or anything.  Simply install  macOS as you normally would.

After you get macOS fixed, go back into iMessage and add back your iCloud account (remove it first if necessary).  This will force iCloud to sync your iPhone’s and Mac’s messages once again.

In the future, if you lose the ability to sync messages, your **first** thing you should try is to log out of iCloud and log back in.  Removing and reinstalling software is usually very low in the list of things to do to solve problems.

Comment: Thanks Allan. I did try to logout and log back in 3 times before decided to removed it. But sure I’ll try your steps now.

Comment: The second thing would be to remove the account and add it back it.  As always - make sure you have a back up!